# Can we implement collapsing Toolbar behaviour in Bottom Appbar?

Tags: android, kotlin, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-bottomappbar

How can we implement collapsing Toolbar behaviour in Bottom Appbar? Is it possible to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Side note : This question is too broad to be considered here. They are better off searched on Google.

However, to answer your question : **yes** you can do that if you want to but there is pretty much no reason to do so. It goes against material design principles, there are no built in components to accomplish this (so you will have to **make your custom views**) and it will also confuse the user since this is not a design seen anywhere in android.

You are better off using a [Bottom app bar with a navigation drawer](https://material.io/design/components/app-bars-bottom.html#) (which pulls up from the bottom instead of the side).